# Override css for specific pinterest buttons

Tags: pinterest

I have added a pinterest button to my site so that if any image is hovered, the pinterest button will show up and you will be able to pin the image to your board:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-color="white"></script>
```

However, on a couple of images, the button sits on top of the site header (which is fixed position to the top of the page) and disappear once the cursor enters the header.  I have been searching but could not find any way to overwrite the inline styles that are applied to the button for specific images.

Any solution I have found is for the older version of the pinterest button where you can easily override the styles in your css file.

Does anyone know how to do this for the new button?

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem - you cannot click the button for the top two images](https://jsfiddle.net/b84hjnfk/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  the end I made my own plugin to loop through all images on the page and create a link which I then had complete control over.

As long as the link href was formatted in the following way, it seemed to work:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=[full url of web page]&amp;media=[full url of image]&amp;description=[image title]
```